# Manually calculate variance from count data for categorical ratings

Tags: r

I am trying to manually calculate the variance (and mean) from categorical rating count data.

```
Item <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
cat1 <- c(4,12,17,NA)
cat2 <- c(NA,10,20,15)
cat3 <- c(17,5,12,6)
cat4 <- c(10,12,17,NA)
cat5 <- c(3,21,NA,16)
cat6 <- c(2,14,12,20)
cat7 <- c(7,NA,18,23)

Data <- data.frame(Item=Item, Never=cat1,Rarely=cat2,Occasionally=cat3, Sometimes=cat4,Frequently=cat5,Usually=cat6,Always=cat7,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Data

  Item Never Rarely Occasionally Sometimes Frequently Usually Always
1    A     4     NA           17        10          3       2      7
2    B    12     10            5        12         21      14     NA
3    C    17     20           12        17         NA      12     18
4    D    NA     15            6        NA         16      20     23
```

Each categorical rating has an equivalent numeric value (1:7). I have calculated the average numerical rating for each Item as follows:

```
Rating_wt <- 1:7 # Vector of weights for each frequency rating
Rating.wt.mat <- rep(Rating_wt,each=dim(Data[,2:8])[1])
Data$Avg_rating <- rowSums(Data[,2:8]*Rating.wt.mat,na.rm=TRUE)/rowSums(Data[,2:8],na.rm=TRUE)

Data

  Item Never Rarely Occasionally Sometimes Frequently Usually Always Avg_rating
1    A     4     NA           17        10          3       2      7   3.976744
2    B    12     10            5        12         21      14     NA   3.837838
3    C    17     20           12        17         NA      12     18   3.739583
4    D    NA     15            6        NA         16      20     23   5.112500
```

I would like to also calculate the variance for each Average and store that as a new variable in Data.

I believe I need to subtract the Average for each item from each numeric rating and multiply that value by the count in each respective cell, then sum those results across rows, then divide by the total counts in each row.

But, I can't figure out how to set up the element-wise calculations to accomplish that.

Conceptually, I think it should be something like this:

```
Data$Rating_var <- rowSums((Numeric_Rating - Avg_rating)*Value,na.rm=TRUE)/rowSums(Data[,2:8],na.rm=TRUE))
```

Where `Numeric_Rating` corresponds to `Rating_wt`:

```
Never = 1
Rarely = 2
Occasionally = 3
Sometimes = 4
Frequently = 5
Usually = 6
Always = 7
```

and `Value` is the corresponding cell for each `Numeric_Rating` by `Item` intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try to reshape your dataset before you apply your calculations, as it will be easier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


Item <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
cat1 <- c(4,12,17,NA)
cat2 <- c(NA,10,20,15)
cat3 <- c(17,5,12,6)
cat4 <- c(10,12,17,NA)
cat5 <- c(3,21,NA,16)
cat6 <- c(2,14,12,20)
cat7 <- c(7,NA,18,23)

Data <- data.frame(Item=Item, Never=cat1,Rarely=cat2,Occasionally=cat3, Sometimes=cat4,Frequently=cat5,Usually=cat6,Always=cat7,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


Data %>%
  gather(category, value, -Item) %>%                                                  # reshape dataset
  mutate(Rating = recode(category, "Never"=1,"Rarely" = 2,"Occasionally" = 3,         
                                   "Sometimes" = 4,"Frequently" = 5,
                                   "Usually" = 6,"Always" = 7)) %>%                   # assign rating 
  group_by(Item) %>%                                                                  # for each item
  mutate(Avg = sum(Rating*value, na.rm=T) / sum(value, na.rm=T),                      # calculate Avg
         variance = sum(abs(Rating - Avg)*value, na.rm=T) / sum(value, na.rm=T)) %>%  # calculate Variance using the Avg
  ungroup() %>%                                                                       # forget the grouping
  select(-Rating) %>%                                                                 # no need the rating any more
  spread(category, value) %>%                                                         # reshape back to original form
  select_(.dots = c(names(Data), "Avg", "variance"))                                  # get columns in the desired order


# # A tibble: 4 x 10
#    Item Never Rarely Occasionally Sometimes Frequently Usually Always      Avg variance
# * <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     A     4     NA           17        10          3       2      7 3.976744 1.326122
# 2     B    12     10            5        12         21      14     NA 3.837838 1.530314
# 3     C    17     20           12        17         NA      12     18 3.739583 1.879991
# 4     D    NA     15            6        NA         16      20     23 5.112500 1.529062
```

Try to run the piped process step by step to see how it works, especially if you're not familiar with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` syntax.

Comment: I get an error with the above: `Error in recode(category, Never = 1, Rarely = 2, Occasionally = 3, Sometimes = 4,  : 
  unused arguments (Never = 1, Rarely = 2, Occasionally = 3, Sometimes = 4, Frequently = 5, Usually = 6, Always = 7)`

Comment: I fixed the unused argument error by explicitly calling the dplyr recode and select functions. But, I get the same values for Avg and variance for all four items.

Comment: After some searching, I tried detaching plyr - problem solved!
Thanks!

Comment: I had the variance calculation wrong initially.
Using the accepted answer, it should be  `mutate(Avg_freq_score = sum(Rating*value, na.rm=T) / sum(value, na.rm=T),                      # calculate Avg
         Freq_var = sum(((Rating - Avg_freq_score)^2)*value, na.rm=T) / sum(value, na.rm=T))`